Problems related to permissions for non-root users and Docker volumes
I'm using Docker to set up isolated development environments.
So I configured the dockerfile to create a non-root user. (Using the official Ubuntu image as a base)
I created a volume for file management, but a permission problem occurred.
reviewed several solutions for this. :

chmod 777 -R volume (this is a stupid method but effective)
Match with the same PID/GID as the user on the host (I think this method works fine)

I wanted to apply solution number 2, but the problem was as follows.

user on the host is 1000:1000 (UID:GID).
user on the guest is 1001:1001(UID:GID).
In the guest, 1000:1000 is already in use by a user named "ubuntu".

However, it does not seem desirable to modify the external environment to use Docker. So, I decided not to create a user with 1001:1001.
The user named “ubuntu” is an account that has already been created as shown below.
$ docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
Digest: sha256:3f85b7caad41a95462cf5b787d8a04604c8262cdcdf9a472b8c52ef83375fe15
Status: Image is up to date for ubuntu:latest
docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest

What's Next?
  1. Sign in to your Docker account → docker login
  2. View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview ubuntu

$ docker run --rm ubuntu cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
_apt:x:42:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
ubuntu:x:1000:1000:Ubuntu:/home/ubuntu:/bin/bash <-- ??


What I want to know:

What does the user “ubuntu” exist for?
Can I use “ubuntu” or replace it with another account?
If "ubuntu" is for special purposes, I would like to create a GID to access the volume and use umask. If there is a better solution, please share it.

I am looking for a flexible and generalized method for this problem that is not affected by the external environment.

(1) In the Container, UID 1000 and UID 1000 in the Host have the same permissions to grant UID 1000 access to the same directory. It does not matter whether the user name of UID 1000 corresponds to ubuntu (container) or to For demouser (HOST). (2) If you just want the volume Folder corresponding to the Container to be directly accessible to the Host User (UID 1000), and there is a User with UID 1000 in the Container, you can directly use this user account, no need to do anything. Other adjustments.

@life888888 I understand that if the username and uid are the same, there is no permission issue. However, in the official Ubuntu image, a user with the same PID as the host user already exists, and I am worried about matching the PID to 1000 because I do not know for what purpose it exists.

default non root user. for general purpose.

You can pass the host user ID into the container when you run it, docker run -u $(id -u); it doesn't specifically need to exist in /etc/passwd in the container.  You need to include this option every time you docker run a temporary container to run a command in it.
